# Sending retry Mail Queue laravel with other password smtp

Tags: php, laravel, email, message-queue, laravel-artisan

I have a problem. I have queue failed email because smtp password is wrong.
When I changed to true smtp password then execute `./artisan queue:retry` all.
And then the result all of email is back to failed queues and still failed.

how to solve this problem ? 
are queue:failed save my wrong smtp account before?

Comment: are you using REDIS driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will throw the error because those request with bad passwords are already in queue and you need to reset the queue manually.

If you are using REDIS driver do below

```
Redis::connection()->del('queues:myqueue');
```

or you can manually delete from redis command line tools

If you are using database driver do the following

```
DB::table('jobs')->delete();
```

for beanstalkd refer below

https://gist.github.com/lukaswhite/8882024

Comment: it possible using ./artisan queue:flush ?

Comment: Queue flush will just clear the failed job , pending jobs will be still there